# Impact on deleting AWS User

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-fargate

One of our teammate left and I was wondering what would happen if I delete his AWS IAM user ?

Will I get an issue with the resources he built (Fargte tasks, Cloudwatch rules etc) ?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: De-activate or delete his/hers access keys. Don't have to delete the user-itself immediately if you are not sure of its impact. See what happens and after a while you can re-considere deleting.

Comment: IAM users do not own the resources they create. All the resources are owned by the root AWS account. Deleting an IAM user should have no affect at all, unless that user hard-coded their API keys inside a service somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Deleting a user won't affect anything that was created by that user.

There is, of course, the possibility that the user acted maliciously, crafting some sort of conditional based on their username or access key ID (although this isn't easy; CloudFormation, for example, doesn't provide the invoking user to the template).

A more likely problem is if they acted incompetently, storing their access key / secret key in some configuration file. This will cause the applications to fail whether you delete the user or disable their access keys.

Regardless, it's worth searching your codebase and deployments for both their username and their access keys.

If you don't want to delete the user outright, then be sure to disable their access keys (as @Marcin said), along with their ability to login via the Console.